# Display custom onReceivedError screen

Tags: android, error-handling, webview

In my WebView app I want to have a custom onReceivedError screen. [image: Web page not avalible]

Instead I want to launch a custom xml defined view with the possibility to do some actions. (Much easier from the same class as the webview).

What is the most simple and reliable replacement for this screen? Dialog or some sort of setContentView? It would look much better if the standard "web page not found" is never shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an xml holding the webview.

And in the onReceivedError method, show a dialog which alerts the user. On click of the ok button you can reload the webview of hide the webview as needed

Comment: If I press the BACK button while the dialog is shown, I still see the Web page not found error.

Comment: you can setCancelable(false) for the dialog. So it wont get cancelled on back press. so user will have to press the ok button

Comment: Ok I make a Custom dialog to the screen. Thanks!

Comment: You should be careful when using onReceivedError with a WebView. It may get triggered also on JavaScript errors after the page loads (e.g. the page loads fine but post document.Ready JS code tries to get to a Url and get Http 404, triggers the onReceivedError and your thinks there is a problem reaching the original URL).
You should always check what error you got and if the URL is the same as the WebView's URL.